# XMLからHTMLへの変換方法

Tags: html, xml, xsl

表題の通りになります。
例えば以下のようなXMLがあった場合。

```
<rootview>
  <paper>
    <size>A4</size>
  </paper>
  <childviews>
    <view i:type="textbox">
      <x>100</x>
      <y>50</y>
    </view>
  </childviews>
</rootview>
```

htmlとしてテキストボックスをx座標、y座標に指定して配置したいです。
(i:typeにはコンボボックスなど他のコンポーネントも入ります)
xsltを使えばできるのかと思うところまで行きましたが実際の方法がわかりません。
何か方法やサンプルなどご教示していただければ幸いです。
もちろんxsltではなく他の実現方法でも結構です。

よろしくお願い致します。

--------2016/07/24--------
進展がありましたのでご報告します。

xslファイルとして以下を記述しました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match='rootview'>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Questions</title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="paper"/>
        aaa
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="childviews/view"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="paper">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="size=A4">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="A4.css"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="childviews/view">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@type='textbox'">
        <input type="text">
          <xsl:attribute name='style'>position: absolute; left: <xsl:value-of select="x"/>px; top: <xsl:value-of select="y"/>px</xsl:attribute>
        </input>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

このxslファイルとxmlファイルをもとにC#にて以下のコードでhtmlファイルを生成しました。

```
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

    xslt.Load(@"D:\sample.xsl");

    XPathDocument xpathDocument = new XPathDocument(@"D:\sample.xml");

    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"D:\sample.html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    xslt.Transform(xpathDocument, writer);
```

出力されたhtmlが以下です。

```
<html><head><title>Questions</title></head><body><input type="text" style="position: absolute; left: 100; top: 50px" /></body></html>
```

ブラウザで開くと一見できたように見えますが、`<xsl:template match="paper">`が反映されないのです。`(<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="A4.css"/>・・`となって欲しい)
引き続き調査しますが原因がお分かりの方、お力添えよろしくお願いします。
ちなみにxmlの「i:type」をxslで「xsl:when test="@i:type」と書くとコロンがNGとエラーが出てしまったため、xmlを「type」とし「xsl:when test="@type」としました。
このコロンについてもエスケープするなどして使える方法を探しています。

Comment: 進展ありましたので質問内容を修正しました。metropolisさま、ご指摘ありがとうございます。XMLは脱字です。それとxsl:templateを使用するようにしました。（match=ではなくselect=ですよね？）また、冒頭サンプルのXMLも正確なものでなかったので修正しました。引き続き知見をお借りできれば幸いです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。「'A4'」としても結果は変わらずです。試しに<xsl:template match="paper">の直後に<xsl:text>hoge</xsl:text>と書いてみてもhtmlのhead部分に「hoge」が出力されないのでpaperタグが解釈できていないように見受けられるのですが原因が分からずといったところです。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。上手くいかない原因がC#で指定しているxmlがテスト用の別のものを指していました。。お騒がせして大変申し訳ありません。ちなみに「<xsl:stylesheet version = '2.0'・・」としてもどちらも上手くいき結果は変わらずでした。ご尽力頂きありがとうございました！

Comment: `i:type` のようなコロンの使用は`i` がネームスペースであることを表します。

Comment: ネームスペースであることは理解しています。サンプルのXMLはWPFの画面すなわちXAMLファイルをXMLに変換したものなのですが、「i:」が自動的に付与されてしまうようなので対応できないかご相談させて頂きました。

Comment: XML に `xmlns:i ="..."`のようなネームスペースの定義部分があるはずで、XSLTでも同じようにネームスペースを指定する必要があります。 [参考](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/xml/library/x-xsltmistakes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメント権限がないため回答にて失礼いたします．（すでに解決されたと思いますが）

以下のようなXML、XSLTスタイルシートでHTMLを得ることができるはずです．

入力XMLファイル

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootview xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <paper>
        <size>A4</size>
    </paper>
    <childviews>
        <view i:type="textbox">
            <x>100</x>
            <y>50</y>
        </view>
    </childviews>
</rootview>
```

XSLTスタイルシート

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' 
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="i">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match='rootview'>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Questions</title>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="paper"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="childviews/view"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paper">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="size = 'A4'">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="A4.css"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="childviews/view">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@i:type='textbox'">
            <input type="text">
                <xsl:attribute name='style'>position: absolute; left: <xsl:value-of select="x"/>px; top: <xsl:value-of select="y"/>px</xsl:attribute>
            </input>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

結果のHTML

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Questions</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="A4.css">
   </head>
   <body><input type="text" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 50px"></body>
</html>
```

コメントを拝見していて気が付きましたが

> xsl のバージョンを 2.0 に変更した場合に結果は変わりますか？

.netのマイクロソフトのXSLTプロセッサはバージョン１のXSLT勧告しかサポートしません．従ってversion="2.0"とするのは、それをサポートする、SaxonやXmlPrimeを使用した場合のみ有効になります．.netのマイクロソフトのXSLTプロセッサを使用する限り（現時点では）意味がありません．

Saxon API for .NET
http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnet/dotnetapi.html

XmlPrime XML Processing for the .NET Framework
https://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/index.htm

BLUEPIXYさんが指摘しておられるように、i:typeという属性が入力XMLに存在するならそれに対応するネームスペース宣言を入力XMLとXSLTスタイルシートの両方に書かねばなりません．私はXAMLをやったのは随分昔で、正確なネームスペースを覚えておりませんので暫定的に"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"を使用させていただきました．

以上 お役に立てば幸いです．

Comment: BLUEPIXYさま、tmakitaさまご回答ありがとうございます。確かにXMLにネームスペースの宣言が記述されており、xsl:stylesheetの宣言部にそのネームスペースを定義することで解決することができました。以上をもって解決とさせて頂きます。ちなみにxslのバージョンを2.0に変更しても結果に変わりはありませんでした。今のところ2.0以上の機能は必要ないので問題ありません。